# Any [revisions] which aren't a [revision]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have both [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revision) and [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisions), the latter without wiki.

Is there anyone able to find a relevant difference between them?
As I see it, the singular should merged by a moderator, not just synonymized.

Comment: You run the risk of someone "reinventing" that tag.

Comment: @wheaties The moderator who merges them can also set one as a synonym for the other, preventing it from being re-created.

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there as long as we're bringing it up: would [tag:revision] be a burninate candidate, or does it make sense to keep?

Comment: I'm considering doing this (merging + synonymizing [revision] -> [revisions]). **Does anyone have objections?**

Comment: @jpmc26 i agree!

Comment: @durron597: the older question explicitly says to ask on meta if you aren't sure about the merge, either because you're not sure if the tags are synonyms, or because you're not sure either tag is even valid.